# phantomjs - error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8

Tags: node.js, linux, phantomjs, shared-libraries

I get an error when running phantomjs

## code

```
var path = require('path');
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var phantomjs = require('/var/bin/node_modules/phantomjs25-beta/bin/phantomjs');
var binPath = phantomjs.path

console.log('test');
```

## error

```
# node phantomjs.js
test
/var/bin/node_modules/phantomjs25-beta/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

libjpeg.so.8 belongs to Debian Jessie environment.
You may download [here](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/libjpeg8/download) the library and put it inside the folder supposed to be needed in.